# How to create production quality "high density" tables (e.g. statistical tables) and mathematical formulae in scribus?

Tags: latex, scribus

I have justv started using Scribus. I am thinking of creating an academic publication using Scribus. The publication will have a lot of statistical tables and mathematical formulae.

I am thinking of using Latex (also new to me), to create the tables and equations (since I don't think Scribus supports equations and complicated tables out of the box AFAIK) - but I don't know how to incorporate Latex with Scribus.

Any help on how I may do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use LaTeX in the first place? LaTeX is capapable of producing publication quality books, so it might be actually easier to use one tool for the job. There are some ways to manage big LaTeX projects (e.g. split different chapters into different files, put different files needed in the project in different directories.